# How is it possible that when you divide 1 by 9,899, you get two-digit Fibonacci numbers also being carried, etc.?

Tags: fractions

When I divided $1$ by $9,899$, I got two-digit Fibonacci numbers also being carried: $0.0001010203050813213455904636\dots$

When I divided $1$ by $89$, I got one-digit Fibonacci numbers at the beginning: $0.0112359\dots$ (there was originally an eight, but there was carrying and it changed to a nine)

How does all of this happen?  There *is* more than this, you know.  What do you think is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the [generating function of the Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Power_series) is $\frac x{1-x-x^2}$.  At $x=0.01$, this is $\frac {100}{9899}$.